# Problema com Input dinâmico

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estou desenvolvendo um input dinâmico que verifica se no banco de dados consta um valor se houver esse valor não deve aparecer no input, porém estou tento problemas com a minha lógica:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('library.php');
$hoje = date('d/m/Y');
$amanha = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+1),date("Y"))); 
$damanha = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+2),date("Y")));



$predata = $_POST['predata'];
 //Realizo a consulta no banco  de dados
$sql = "SELECT Hora FROM tbl_agenda WHERE Data = '$predata'";

 //Atualizo algumas informações
$atualizahoje = "UPDATE tbl_agenda SET Data='". $hoje ."' WHERE id=33";
$atualizaamanha = "UPDATE tbl_agenda SET Data='". $amanha ."' WHERE id=34";
$atualizadamanha  = "UPDATE tbl_agenda SET Data='". $damanha ."' WHERE id=35";
$qr1 = mysql_query($atualizahoje) or die(mysql_error());
$qr2 = mysql_query($atualizaamanha) or die(mysql_error());
$qr3 = mysql_query($atualizadamanha) or die(mysql_error());
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$ln1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr1);
$ln2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr2);
$ln3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr3);


    echo '<option value="">Selecione..</option>';

// Realizo o while verificando os critérios e adicionando o select ao campo
           while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){

           if($ln['Hora'] != "00:00") {
           echo '<option value="00:00">00:00</option>';


            }
           else {
            echo '<option hidden value="00:00">00:00</option>';
           } 

            if($ln['Hora'] != "01:00") {
              echo '<option value="01:00">01:00</option>';

            }
            else {

             echo '<option hidden value="01:00">01:00</option>';
                }


                 if($ln['Hora'] != "02:00") {
                   echo '<option value="02:00">02:00</option>';
            }
            else {
              echo '<option hidden value="02:00">02:00</option>';
                }



                 if($ln['Hora'] != "03:00") {
                  echo '<option value="03:00">03:00</option>';

            }
            else {
               echo '<option hidden value="03:00">03:00</option>';
                }



                 if($ln['Hora'] != "04:00") {
                 echo '<option value="04:00">04:00</option>';

            }
            else {
        echo '<option hidden value="04:00">04:00</option>';
                }



                 if($ln['Hora'] != "05:00") {

                 echo '<option value="05:00">05:00</option>';

            }
            else {
            echo '<option hidden value="05:00">05:00</option>';
                }



                 if($ln['Hora'] != "06:00") {
            echo '<option value="06:00">06:00</option>';
            }
            else {
             echo '<option hidden value="06:00">06:00</option>';
                }



        if($ln['Hora'] != "07:00") {
            echo '<option value="07:00">07:00</option>';
            }
            else {
             echo '<option hidden value="07:00">07:00</option>';
                }



                 if($ln['Hora'] != "08:00") {
            echo '<option value="08:00">08:00</option>';
            }
            else {
             echo '<option hidden value="08:00">08:00</option>';
                }



                  if($ln['Hora'] != "09:00") {
            echo '<option value="09:00">09:00</option>';
            }
            else {
             echo '<option hidden value="09:00">09:00</option>';
                }



                 if($ln['Hora'] != "10:00") {
            echo '<option value="10:00">10:00</option>';
            }
            else {
             echo '<option hidden value="10:00">10:00</option>';
                }
```

No banco de dados eu tenho o registro `Data = 28/06/2016 e Hora = 00:00`, no meu input então ao selecionar o dia 28/06/2016 o valor de 00:00 não deveria ser exibido, já fiz o teste do `$_POST` e o valor esta chegando corretamente, acredito que o erro está dentro do While.

Comment: No banco de dados, qual é o tipo do campo da data: DATE, DATETIME ou VARCHAR?

Comment: Bom dia, o campo é TEXT.

Comment: Você quer listar todos os horários e não mostrar o que estiver no banco, é isso?

Comment: Isso eu quero listar de 00:00 as 23:00, porém se no banco de dados tiver o valor 01:00 eu quero que o input fique assim 00:00 - 02:00 - 03:00 [...]

Comment: Você esta usando "hidden" não seria melhor não imprimir?

Comment: Já tentei Ivan, o hidden foi a ultima tentativa, o problema é que no banco eu tenho diversos valores, hoje por exemplo eu tenho 4, na primeira rodada o loop hora é = 00:00 na segunda é = 01:00 (Nesse momento aparece o 00:00 e apaga o 01:00. Eu preciso criar uma lógica que não ocorra esse problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que seria isso que você precisa (**obs:** fiz até 24, correto?)...

```
$horas_hidden = array();
while ($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)) {
    $horas_hidden[] = $ln['Hora'];
}
echo montarOptions($horas_hidden, 24);

function montarOptions($horas_hidden, $total_horas)
{
    $html='<option value="">Selecione..</option>';
    for ($i=0; $i <= $total_horas; $i++) {
        $hora = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
        $hora .=':00';

        if (in_array($hora, $horas_hidden)) {
            //hidden só para HTML5
          $html.= "<option hidden value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
        } else {
          $html.= "<option value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
        }
   }
   return $html;
}
```

Comment: Está imprimindo os valores assim : "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" e repetindo, estou olhando e tentando ajustar.

Comment: editei, era o sinal de += mudei para .=

Comment: O problema de aparecer o valor que está no banco de dados persistiu.

Comment: Mas não era pra aparecer isso para cada dado da coleção? Se não, então você pode filtrar usar "group by" no banco, Ou invés de fazer while, pegar somente o primeiro registro do array.

Comment: O que está vindo dessa consulta? `$sql = "SELECT Hora FROM tbl_agenda WHERE Data = '$predata' ";`

Comment: Só uma observação: [depois leia isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: 00:00 /
01:00 /
03:00 /
10:00

Comment: Veja agora se é isso que vc quer?

Comment: Aparentemente resolveu, vou realizar mais alguns testes e volto para confirmar como solucionado, obrigado amigo.